# Rails compiles sass partials without any reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, precompile

I am building a Rails application and I am in front of a weird issue in production: when capistrano compile assets Rails want to create a css version of all partials I included in application.sass and it breaks the deploy because of the variables and mixins I used in this partials.

**In my application.sass**:

```
@import compass
@import header // _header.sass file  
@import footer // _footer.sass file  
@import content // _content.sass file  
...
```

I don't understand why because in another project I don't have this problem.

**Here is my assets.rb file**:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.2'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( email.css newsletter.css maintenance.css noscript.css )
```

Does anyone knows how can I tell Rails to not compile all partials in css files ?
Thanks for your help !

**My application**:
- gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
- gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
- gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails', branch: 'master'
- gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1'
- gem 'spring', '~> 1.3.4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours and hours on all the web, I finally discovered the guilty: Froala gem

By looking to the source of the plugin, and the list of precompiled assets, they have a folder called 'plugins' which has the same name as a personal folder. This was meaning my plugins folder with sass partials was also compiled ! The way to fix it was to rename my own 'plugin' folder.